# Why does `instanceof` error rather than return `false` when used for 2 incompatible classes?

Tags: java, inheritance, instanceof

I'm reading this:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.20.2

They say:

> Consider the example program:
>
> ```
> class Point { int x, y; }
> class Element { int atomicNumber; }
> class Test {
>         public static void main(String[] args) {
>                 Point p = new Point();
>                 Element e = new Element();
>                 if (e instanceof Point) {       // compile-time error
>                         System.out.println("I get your point!");
>                         p = (Point)e;           // compile-time error
>                 }
>         }
> }
> ```
>
> The `instanceof` expression is incorrect because no instance of `Element` or any of its possible subclasses (none are shown here) could possibly be an instance of any subclass of `Point`.

Why does this result in an error, rather than simply in `instanceof` returning false?

Comment: It sounds like you're previous experience might be with languages which were mostly loosely typed and mostly interpreted (ex: most BASICs) as opposed to strongly typed and compiled. With a language that is mostly interpreted, almost all type-like validation occurs at run-time. However, with compiled languages, the compiler is able to do quite a bit of "type and execution flow analysis". As a result, if it finds pathways that can never be executed, it can remove the code in that pathway (i.e. dead code removal). And it generates an error if it finds an operation that cannot ever succeed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`instanceof` check is a runtime check. The compiler is able to discover that this condition is incorrect at compile time (much earlier), so it tells you that it is wrong. Always remember, that failing fast is a good practice, it will save you a lot of time and nerves.

Comment: Thank you - this explains the rational for this decision.  It completely makes sense, indeed, to error at compile time rather than have a `false` result at run time.

Answer (score 11):

I'd say, because you know at compile-time that it will never be true. Therefore, it's safe to assume this is not what the programmer meant :)

However, there probably is a more java-technical explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Because the compiler knows that is impossible to an Element be a Point, so you get an compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the inheritance tree. if A inherited from B then you can write A instance of B

```
Integer i = 3;

System.out.println(i instanceof String); // compile time error

System.out.println(i instanceof Number); // true

System.out.println(i instanceof Object); // true
```